# On receive(), send msg.value to another contract

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I'm attempting to use a new smart contract as a proxy to another contract. The goal is that when this new contract receives Ether, it immediately sends that Ether to the other contract.

I keep getting the error

```
Error: Transaction reverted: contract call run out of gas and made the transaction revert
```

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
receive() external payable {
  require(msg.value >= .01 ether, "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"); 
  executeMint(msg.value / .01 ether); 
}


function executeMint(uint256 numberOfMints) internal {
  payable(_nftContractAddy).transfer(msg.value); 
}
```

Any insight as to why this might be failing?

NOTE: The other contract does have a receive() function and it works as expected when I send Ether to it directly from a wallet.

Comment: Without more info, these are guesses, but 1. Are you sure _nftContractAddy can receive ETH? If must have a payable fallback/receive function in order for this to work, 2. Are you sure you're sending enough ETH with your testing?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could include an Etherscan link for the failing tx.

Comment: @natewelch_ Yes the other contract can receive ETH. It has a receive function and works as expected when sending ETH to it from a wallet. As for gas, I've tried sending the maximum allowable gas limit and the still get this error.

Comment: @AhmedIhsanTawfeeq This is happening in local testing. Contract is not deployed yet.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you have a couple of issues in the contract. Most notable one is that you're not using the defined `numberOfMints` input parameter in `executeMint(uint256 numberOfMints)`, and instead you're using `msg.value`.

Comment: @AhmedIhsanTawfeeq I agree with you there. The plan will be to use that parameter eventually but I need to get the transfer working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sending eth from one contract to another, don't use `.transfer` or `.transfer`, use `.call`, since `transfer` and `send` forward a maximum of 2300 gas units. `call` forwards all the gas. This way, the other contract can do more operations without running out of gas.

Something like:

```js
function executeMint(uint256 numberOfMints) internal {
  payable(_nftContractAddy).call{value: msg.value}(""); 
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/security-considerations.html?highlight=transfer#sending-and-receiving-ether